# Como Funciona el estandar acid en EF 5.(c#) usando Mysql,dbcontext y transacciones?

Tags: mysql, c#

El siguiente método realiza 4 inserciones a 4 diferentes tipos de tablas en el mismo contexto que esta configurado en mysql ( Mysql.EntityFrameWorkCore 5 ) usando transacción.

Mi problema es el siguiente al realizar las 4 inserciones quiero hacer un rollback intencional que indique en el código para que no se efectue ningun cambio. esto lo hago a manera de depurar mi código y ver si respeta el estándar ACID pero ocurre lo siguiente cuando se ejecuta la linea SaveChangesAsync() todo se guarda y luego cuando llega a la linea del rollback los cambios se reflejan en mi base de datos MySQL luego de terminar la ejecucion. no entiendo porque ocurre esto. o desconosco como trabaja mysql en EF :(.

Solo tengo ese problema con mysql no se si es error de mi parte por no conocer como funcionan las transacciones en mysql ya que he usado sql y funciona tal cual.

Comment: veo que mySql tiene una propiedad "AutoCommit" ya intentaste deshabilitarlo al abrir la transacción?

Comment: No se mucho sobre los metodos de mysql en transacciones primera vez que intento hacer un codigo de esta manera.

Comment: con la variable transactionMysql no encuentro ninguna propiedad autocommit :( . mi limitante es que estoy usando IDbContextTransaction en realidad no entiendo muy bien solo veo ejemplos de como hacerlo pero no usan este tipo de objetos IDbContectTransaction... T_T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre el motivo por el cual no podia ejecutar transacciones, Luego de tanto investigar. La causa es el tipo de motor de almacenamiento que usaban las tablas de mysql con las que trabaje usando transacciones.

https://www.arsys.es/blog/myisam-o-innodb-elige-tu-motor-de-almacenamiento-mysql

luego de cambiar el motor logre ejecutar transacciones normalmente respetando los metodos commit y rollback.

De igual manera ya puedo usar el DbContext como si se tratase de SQl :)

Comment: En resumen, imagino estabas usando MyIsam como motor!?

Comment: Si, efectivamente.